# Populate array with numbers from database

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to figure out the best way to populate an array with numerical values pulled from a database. This is the function I have set up so far:

```
    protected int[] GetBoxes()
    {
        int[] boxes;
        string query = "SELECT DISTINCT Length FROM Products INNER JOIN Baird_Ground_Boxes_Products ON uidBox = ProductId";
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(AbleConnectionStr))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cn.Open();
            using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                { 
                     if (reader["Length"].ToString() !="")
                     {
                          //populate array with the length values returned
                     }
                }                     
            }
        }
        return boxes;
    }
```

There is never a single set of values that could be returned (could be 3, could be 2). I'm getting confused on how to populate the array, like I'm making it too difficult or something. Any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: do you know how to access the fields of the reader .. for example reader["FieldName"].ToString() or var someInt = (int)reader["FieldName"], there are seriously 100's of examples online on how to do this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first sight, you may have multiple rows returned from your query.

```
select distinct Length 
    from Products 
        join Baird_Ground_Boxes_Products 
            on  uidBox = ProductId
```

So, you may as well read out all of your returned rows with a `while loop`.

```
var lengths = new List<string>();

if (reader.HasRows)
    while (reader.Read()) lengths.Add(reader.GetString(0));

return lengths.ToArray();
```

And I wonder whether your field `Length` is really a string. Perhaps should you consider using an integer, since lengths are generally expressed as numbers. If so, than wave the `GetString` method in favour of `GetInt32`, and change your type of list.

```
var length = new List<int>();
lengths.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
```

Comment: +1 I think that it's already an `int` column since he's returning an `int[]`. I assume he wants to skip null-values with the string conversion. Of course `reader.IsDBNull` is the better choice.

Answer (score 2):

You should fill a `List<T>` and finally use it's [`ToArray` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819(v=vs.110).aspx) to create the array:

```
var lengths = new List<int>();
// ...

using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
while (reader.Read())
{
    if(!reader.IsDBNull(0)) 
        lengths.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
}

return lengths.ToArray();
```

I've also used `reader.IsDBNull` instead of `reader["Length"].ToString() !=""` to skip the `null`s. You should consider to remove the `null`s in the first place by using `WHERE Length IS NOT NULL`.